# How to make one Gitlab repository to become a fork of another Gitlab repository if they are separated repositories (not forked)?

Tags: gitlab

A GitHub repository was copied to GitLab. Next, the development was happening simultaneously on GitHub and GitLab over a few months. Then, the GitHub repository was finally moved to GitLab.
Is there a way to assign the first GitLab repository to be the fork of the newly moved repository (which is the parent of the first one)? So that the "fork" indicator is active as on the picture: [fork indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQa5F.png).

Comment: Note that there is no way to do this on Git*Hub* (as far as I know). Fortunately there seems to be a way to do it in Git*Lab*. This is specifically a GitLab question though: forks are not a Git concept, and the APIs for GitHub and GitLab differ. ([tag:fork] is also the wrong tag: it's about the Unix/Linux `fork` system call.) Feel free to put the GitHub tag back if you think this should be searchable there though, since GitHub does have the GitHub/GitLab/Bitbucket kind of fork concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking how to add a forked relation between existing repositories. GitLab provides an API to do this: [Create a forked from/to relation between existing projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#create-a-forked-fromto-relation-between-existing-projects)

> ```
> POST /projects/:id/fork/:forked_from_id
> ```
>
> | Attribute | Type | Required | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `forked_from_id` | ID | ☑ Yes | The ID of the project that was forked from. |
> | `id` | integer/string | ☑ Yes | The ID or [URL-encoded path of the project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#namespaced-path-encoding). |